# HLS streaming, timer for first chunk

Tags: video, streaming, vlc, http-live-streaming

I'm currently setuping an HLS stream server  and I would need to test it with a client. I'm using VLC.
My goal is to know how much time it takes for a client to load a video.
My first thought was to launch the video on VLC and time it with a classic clock but I would need more accurate informations.

Is it possible to get that sort of informations through Vlc command line for example ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

HLS is an adaptive bit rate (ABR) steaming protocol, which may make your measurements hard to generalise.

For ABR streaming, a video is transcoded into multiple different bit rate versions and each version is broken into, for example 10 second, chunks. So if you start with one video and want to support five different bit rates you will have five different streams of chunks.

The client requests the chunks one by one to receive the video, and it can request a lower bit rate chunk if the network conditions are bad and a larger one if the network is good (and it has a display that can make use of it).

Some clients may always start with a low bit rate to speed up the initial playback an then step up through the higher bit rates, while others may be set up to start with a middle bit rate.

So as you can see, the time to start playing will depend on how the player is configured and also on the number of different bit rates streams for the video and the network conditions.